# Login into XFCE session without display manager

Tags: 12.04, xfce, display-manager

I am currently using `lightdm` as my default `display manager` but I feel like there is no need of display manager in my case because I am always going to login to `xfce session`.

So, is there any way I can disable `lightdm` and when I boot next time I am just left with `terminal` where i will enter my `username and password`.

I looked into `nodm` but I was not able to configure it properly.

Comment: The problem with using no display manager is that you cannot lock the session. If you have no dm installed, you will have to log in at a terminal and then run `startx`. I'd use a dm even though I always use the same session because of the lock.

Comment: @queueoverflow: thanks for the advice. Can you suggest me a very lightweight `dm`.

Comment: `xdm` is the lightest I've seen yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get install nodm
```

Then edit `/etc/defaults/nodm` and change this two lines:

```
NODM_ENABLED=true
NODM_USER=root
```

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the configuration of your login shell to launch X automatically after logging into tty. Put something like this into your `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zlogin` (or whatever the config file is for your shell) to lauch X after logging into the first VT:

```
[ "$TTY" = "/dev/tty1" ] && startx
```

Or you can omit the first part and write just "startx".

This way of launching X, however, poses a security risk: when you're away from the keyboard (and of course, you've locked the X session) someone might switch to the tty1, interrupt X (or just move it into the background) and access your computer with your user's account.

To avoid this use:

```
startx &
exit
```

In bash, or `setsid startx` in other shells.